# Caching a file system over the internet

Tags: linux, networking, filesystems, cache

I store all my files on my private server (DSL line, /28 network but still slow, especially the up-stream which is 512kBit). This works well for my smaller files, all my emails, Zarafa etc.

But for larger files (especially Fotos) it is too slow. Furthermore, I want to share the fotos with family. In the LAN this is already done with Samba, each user has a different user (LDAP).

For speeding up internet access, I have a vServer with fast connection but not so much space (10GB).

It would be great if this could be used to speed up the access from internet to the files.

One plan would be to access the files over Samba/NFS over an OpenVPN tunnel, add some cache and then use ownCloud or WebDAV on the vServer.

The caching system would need to support:

1.) Store all accessed files in the cache (10GB) and take it from the cache if they exist. A small meta request could/should be done first to check if the file changed on the master (just modification date)

2.) Files written should be stored into the cache (which is fast) and sequentially updated on the master. When a file is opened for writing, the file might be locked on the master to avoid conflicts

3.) The cache should be always full (10GB) and survive reboots/disconnects. When new space is required a method like LRU or NRU should be used to remove old entries from cache.

I can hardly imagine that there is no solution for that - but I was not able to find one.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Did you consider setting up a scheduled rsync process ? It certainly has less overhead than any filesystem and will only copy changed/updated files. Shameless promotion and example of rsync: https://github.com/paravz/windows-rsync-backup

Comment: Rsync does not work - it's half duplex. What happens if a file is changed on the master and the slave? I though about setting up something like that with unison - but this sounds cumersome, lots of work, unelegant, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cachefilesd and fs-cache. I have no experience with them but their description match your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A cloud storage system such as DropBox, Google Drive, SugarSync, etc., could meet most of your requirements depending on the number and sizes of files.  The tricky item is how to deal with locking/conflicts.

Comment: Of course - anything related to a cloud is what I exactly do NOT want!! Otherwise I could directly use it. My valuable, personal data will never (willingly) enter such a cloud system

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  This wasn't clear from your question since you have a "vServer" which I interpreted as a virtual private server hosted in a datacenter (technically "in the cloud"). Although the answer didn't help you, I'll leave it in case someone else has the same question but is ok with using cloud services.